# Set Up Google Play Games Services Client+Server

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0, google-play-games

I want to accomplish this:
https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/serverlogin
with Java instead of javascript.  I know the APIs exist for Java, as I already have a desktop application and an Android application that are able to login properly to Google, using Java APIs.  Now I just need to figure out how to follow the process described above with regular Java.

This line is particularly annoying:
"If the auth object in my google-signin-callback already has an access token, can I send that to the server instead of performing this additional code-exchange step?
A: No. You should avoid sending access tokens to your server if at all possible. The "exchange a single-use code for an access token" strategy is much more secure and we highly recommend using that approach in your applications."

I have seen things that seem to contradict in several places, including on Google's guides.  This seems like it would be the easiest way given what I have working, but I'd do it properly if I could figure out how in Java.  I want to be able to access Google Play Games Services on the client side as well as the server side.

1) How do I get a single use token on the client side? (on android and desktop)
2) How do I exchange it on the server side?

Thanks